# Excel: Extract a unique distinct list of alphabetically ordered elements from two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to perform the following tasks either using VBA or excel formula: Starting from two column containing some values, I would like to extract in a third column each element with a number of characters lower or equal to 3. Column 3 should contain all the values with length <=3 alphabetically ordered.

For example if we have:

```
Car     Body
Sun     Sun
Bee     Share
Bath    Spot
```

Column 3 should contain

```
Bee 
Car 
Sun
```

Does someone have an idea how can I do it? I tried the advanced filtering option but I didn't manage to give as an input two different columns when indicating the length of the word.

Comment: Your expected output contradicts what you said in the question.  The output shows all values with length = 3, not length > 3.

Comment: yes i am sorry, I corrected the question

Comment: If you have Excel 2010+, you can do this using `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform` in Excel 2016)

Comment: yes, we have an idea how it can be done

Comment: Thank you Banana, really useful comment

Comment: if you are going with formulas, then you will have to split the process into steps. here is step 1 for you: an unsorted list of unique values from columns A&B `=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($F$2:$K$100<>"")*(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$B$100)=0),ROW($2:$100)*100+COLUMN($A:$C),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""` put the formula into column C and hit `Shift+Enter` to activate array formula, and then copy it down the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim it As Range, r As Range, x0
        With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
            For Each it In Range("A1:B4")
                If Len(it.Value) <= 3 Then
                    x0 = .Item(it.Value)
                End If
            Next it

            Set r = Range("C1").Resize(.Count, 1)
            r.Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
            r.Sort [C1], 1
        End With
End Sub
```

This dictionary can extract uniques:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gary's student, it works but elements are not ordered alphabetically.

Comment: @Adric Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim cIn As Range
    Dim cOut As Range
    Dim iLen As Integer

    Set cIn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B4")
    Set cOut = ActiveSheet.Range("D1")
    iLen = 3

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each c In cIn
            If Len(c.Value) <= iLen Then .Item(c.Value) = c.Value
        Next c
        cOut.Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
        cOut.Resize(.Count).Sort Key1:=cOut, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a general formula, so it makes easier for other people to modify.

You can easily remove duplicities using `.RemoveDuplicates` and order alphabetically using `.Sort` inbuilt methods in your own example

```
Private Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B4")
    Dim offsetindex As Integer
    offsetindex = 0

    For Each field In rng

        If (Len(field) <= 3) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Offset(offsetindex, 0) = field
            offsetindex = offsetindex + 1
        End If

    Next field

End Sub
```

Obviously presuming, your (table) range starts A1